# How to get value from drop down and use it to query then show a result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<?php
$qry = " select * from `HX_tableService` ";
$result = mysql_query($qry, $link);
$serviceList = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $serviceList[$row['serviceID']] = $row['serviceName'];  
}

    echo "<select class=\"inputform\" name=\"selectedservice\" required> <option value=\"\">---- select ----</option> ";
    foreach ($serviceList as $serviceID => $serviceName) {
        echo "<option value=\"".$serviceID."\">".$serviceName."</option>";
    }

echo "</selected>";

echo "<table width=\"350px\" border=\"1\" >";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> <input type=\"number\" max = \"100\" min =\"1\"onkeypress=\"validate(event)\" name=\"serieNumber\" placeholder=\"No.\"/ required></td>";
echo "<td> PRINT OUT THE NUMBER </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

This code is my drop-down menu to select services and input the number.

I want to get the result on ( PRINT OUT THE NUMBER ) while typing the number.

```
    -get value from selected series
    -get value from input number box
    -use both value query from my database
    -show result on next column
```

If I'm explain my problem unclear, sorry about that. you can see my attach picture at this link also.

http://www.uppic.org/image-8C74_53C8D1D6.jpg

Sorry for my English also.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what have you got so far?

Comment: with `$('#yourselectbox').val()` you got the value.

Comment: I'd recommend using jQuery to process a change event `$("#something").change(function(){ code here });` on your dropdown, get the value `$(this).val()`, pass it to your PHP using AJAX `$.ajax({ ... })` to then return a result and respond accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Set an id attribute for your input and your target td. After that you can do something like this:

```
$('#number').on('keyup', getData);
$('#selectedservice').on('change', getData);

function getData() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: {
            number: $('#number').val(),
            selectedservice: $('#selectedservice').val()
        }
    })
        .done(function (msg) {
        $('#target').html("Data Saved: " + msg);
    });
}
```